# Executing a function that adds columns and populates them dependig on other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a dataframe that contains a text and result

```
             Text    Result
0  some text...      True
1  another one...    False
```

And I have got a function that does a feature extraction from text - returns dict with about 1000 keys that are words and T/F values depending if the word was in a text.

```
words = ["some", "text", "another", "one", "other", "words"]
def extract(text):
      result = dict()
      for w in words:
             result[w] = (w in text)
      return result
```

Result I am expecting is

```
             Text    some   text  another one    other  words  Result
0  some text...      True   True  False   False  False  False  True
1  another one...    False  False True    True   False  False  False
```

But I don't know how to apply this on a dataframe?
What I have done so far is to create columns with default False value, but I have no clue how to populate it with True values.

```
for feature in words:
    df[feature] = False
```

I guess that there is better way to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.Series.str.get_dummies` with `pd.DataFrame.reindex`

```
exp = (
    df.Text.str.get_dummies(' ')
      .reindex(columns=words, fill_value=0)
      .astype(bool)
)

df.drop('Result', 1).join(exp).join(df.Result)

          Text   some   text  another    one  other  words  Result
0    some text   True   True    False  False  False  False    True
1  another one  False  False     True   True  False  False   False
```

---

**Explanation**

`get_dummies` gives dummy columns for each word found, simple enough.  However, I use reindex in order to represent all the words we care about.  The `fill_value` and `astype(bool)` are there to match OPs output.  I use `drop` and `join(df.Result)` as a pithy way to get `Result` to the end of the dataframe.

Comment: Great answer :-)

Comment: thanks, could you explain how does it work? what is what? Is it not possible to use my function?

Answer (score 0):

You can [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) a function to a dataframe column like this:

```
def func(): # some function that you want to apply to each row in a column
    return None

new_row = df['column_name'].apply(func)
```

After that you can append the `new_row` to your existing dataframe.

There's also a [similar function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) but for applying function to entire dataframe.

Edit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['some text...', 'another one...'], columns=['Text'])
words = ["some", "text", "another", "one", "other", "words"]
def extract(text):
      result = dict()
      for w in words:
             result[w] = (w in text)
      return result.values()
new_cols = pd.DataFrame(df['Text'].apply(extract), columns=words)
result_df = pd.concat([df, new_cols], axis=1)
```

Comment: but I want to apply it on all the rows and add plenty of new columns

Comment: You can use apply to create new dataframe and concatenate it with your initial dataframe (column) with text. See my edit.