# Add new columns to DataFrame from the value of one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, there is a column with values like a,b,c i.e. string splited by ','. Now I want to create new columns, for example, for a,b,c there would be new column a, column b, column c. then the data with a,b,c would get a value of true on the three columns, the data with a,b,e would get true on columns a and b but false on c, maybe it is more clearly to see the picture below. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182255/executing-a-function-that-adds-columns-and-populates-them-dependig-on-other-colu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting pandas column of comma-separated strings into dummy variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867201/converting-pandas-column-of-comma-separated-strings-into-dummy-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with cast to bool by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and add column `B` by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df['A'].str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool).join(df['B'])
print (df1)
       a     b     c      f  B
0   True  True  True  False  3
1  False  True  True   True  4
```

More general solution with [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `A`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a,b,c','b,c,f'], 'B':[3,4], 'C':[7,3]})
print (df)
       A  B  C
0  a,b,c  3  7
1  b,c,f  4  3

df1 = df.pop('A').str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool).join(df)
print (df1)
       a     b     c      f  B  C
0   True  True  True  False  3  7
1  False  True  True   True  4  3
```